# How to return API response if id is not available in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

```
DetailsImpl.java

public detailResponse fetchId(String accId){
Optional<Acc> acc = accRep.findById(accId);
//Here I need to write the logic that if accId is not there in data base than I need to 
show the response from another API and the class service impl class for that is FeeDetails.java.

FeeDetails.java{

@Overeide
public List<Response> getRes(String accId){
return client.getDetailsOfField(accId);
}
```

I need to check if accId is there in database if it is present then logic is working fine but if it's not present than I need to show the response from already existing logic which is written in FeeDetails.java class. I am facing problem in writing the logic as it's giving an internal error when I hit the API.

Comment: The `detailResponse` must be the class , it should be `DetailResponse` as className must start with uppercase letter as a code conventions.

Answer (score 0):

**Optional.isPresent()**

You can check using `Optional.isPresent()`, if the id is present in the database then return data from db else you can call the API to get the existing data.

```
public DetailResponse fetchId(String accId){

            Optional<Acc> acc = accRep.findById(accId);
            if(acc.isPresent()){
                //return from DB
            } else {
                //existing API code
            }
  }
```

Comment: What should I return as there are two conditions now

Comment: @Daboo :  You need to return the `DetailsResponse` object, because the return type of fetchId method is of type DetailsResponse. So, for **if** part you will get the **data from the db** and for **else** part you will get the **data from your existing API**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard format

{"status":"success/failure","message":"your message"}